# How to prevent hiding underlying views with presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiview, visibility

Just like title.
How to prevent it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? A modal view is meant to appear on top of your underlying views. That's what makes it modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The OS is removing 'offscreen' views to conserver video RAM. If you want this behavior, you'll have to animate your view in manually.

Comment: Thanks very much. I resolved this with manual animation like as you mentioned.